# I'm having issues while using codelite ide to enter a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors, mingw

I am having issue to input a 2D array in Codelite IDE. The build log is-

> ```
> C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C ""C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe" -j8 SHELL=cmd.exe -e -f 
> Makefile" "----------Building project:[ test - Debug ]----------"
> mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory
> 'C:/Users/CHIRAYU/Documents/CODING/PRACTICE/array/test' "C:/Program
> Files/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe"  -c 
> "C:/Users/CHIRAYU/Documents/CODING/PRACTICE/array/test/main.cpp" -g
> -O0 -std=c++17 -Wall  -o Debug/main.cpp.o -I. -I. during RTL pass: expand C:/Users/CHIRAYU/Documents/CODING/PRACTICE/array/test/main.cpp:
> In function 'int main()':
> C:/Users/CHIRAYU/Documents/CODING/PRACTICE/array/test/main.cpp:10:9:
> internal compiler error: in make_decl_rtl, at varasm.c:1322
>      int matrix[m][n]={};
>          ^~~~~~ libbacktrace could not find executable to open Please submit a full bug report, with preprocessed source if appropriate. See
> <https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64> for instructions.
> mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [test.mk:98: Debug/main.cpp.o] Error 1
> mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory
> 'C:/Users/CHIRAYU/Documents/CODING/PRACTICE/array/test'
> mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:5: All] Error 2
> ====1 errors, 0 warnings====
> ```

The code used is-

```
//entering a matrix of user input size and displaying it 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int m{},n{}; //m- number of rows; n - number of columns
    cout<<"Enter the number of rows and columns separated by space "<<endl;
    cin>> m >> n;
    
    int matrix[m][n]={};
    
    for(int i{0}; i<m; i++){
        for(int j{0}; j<n; j++){
            cout<<"Enter the "<<i<<" x "<<j<<" element"<<endl;
            cin>>matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    cout<<"The entered matrix is: "<<endl;
    for(int a{0}; a<n; a++){
        for(int b{0}; b<n; b++){
            cout<<matrix[a][b]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`int matrix[m][n]={};` is a static array. A static array is resolved at compile time and cannot be resized at runtime. When you usually try to do something like this, the compiler and the editor (if you have an editor which flags errors like that) will tell you that the size must be a constant (`m` and `n`).

You can get the code to work using `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` as follow,

```cpp
#include <vector>

...

std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(m, std::vector<int>(n));
```

Comment: But how the same code is run by other IDE?

Comment: @Chirayu The default value of `m` and `n` is 0 (at compile time and runtime as you initialized it). So the size of the `matrix` is `int matrix[0][0];`. Some IDEs (ie: Visual Studio) issues an error when you try to do something like this. Some IDEs don't.